# STM32 HAL - writing to EEPROM (I2C)

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal, eeprom

I'm learning to program in HAL and today I wanted to save some data to an external I2C EEPROM. The problem is that I cannot get the EEPROM to send an ACK after I send the address. I tried it using an Arduino (on 5V and also 3V) and the IC responded with an ACK. I tried to connect an MLX90614 I2C IR sensor and it worked fine (I got the response and I could send and receive data both in Arduino and STM32). I also swapped the SDA and SCL leads thinking that I might have mixed them, but this was not the case. I used a logic analyzer and as You can see I got only an NACK. I don't think that the EEPROM IC (ATMLU036/2EB - AT24C256B) doesn't like 3V because it worked in Arduino and the datasheet says that it will work fine even at lower voltages. I have no clue why it is not working and why other I2C peripherals (such as IR sensor) worked just fine. I am using STM32F429ZI - DISC1. Here is my code: (in short I used pins PB8 for SCL and PB9 for SDA, I tried 100kHz, 10kHz, 1kHz scl frequency, but it didn't help. In STM32CubeMX I didn't change anything - the lines have internal pull-up resistors)

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  *
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  uint8_t d = 0xfc;

  HAL_I2C_Mem_Write( &hi2c1, (0b1010000 << 1), 0x00, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &d, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, 1000 );

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1){

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* I2C1 init function */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 10000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/** Pinout Configuration
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  file: The file name as string.
  * @param  line: The line in file as a number.
  * @retval None
  */
void _Error_Handler(char *file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
  */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

I have read somewhere, that this might be caused by the IC writing something, but in my example it isn't. I just wanted the device to answer, I didn't write anything to EEPROM cells. I have also written a simple I2C address scanner (for STM32 and I tried an Arduino I2C address scanner) and it's the same story: IR sensor responded with ACK (on address 0x5A) and EEPROM responded with NACK on every possible 7-bit address :\ (also on 0x50, the A0, A1, A2 address pins are tied to GND, I also tried it with external pull-up resistors, but as You can guess, It didn't work). Please help me or give me a hint why this setup is not working. [I2C data transmission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jmAJ.png)

Sorry for my grammar mistakes, I'm still learning English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that I have found the answer. And the problem was: (drum rolls) huge capacitance. I plugged SDA and SCL into my oscilloscope and [I saw this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIXgn.png). Then I unplugged SDA and SCL cables from my breadboard and inserted them directly into [oscilloscope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Wwr.png). (Some buses are low at start, because I restarted STM32). After this I added 1K pull-up resistors (instead of the built into STM32 and (in testing) external 10K) and got this nice [data transmission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9cVx.png). Next I confirmed that everything works [using PulseView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEHPI.png). Thanks to everyone that have read my problem and spend some time tinkering why this was not working. I guess that MLX90614esf is less sensitive to big capacitance (or it has lower value resistors for internal pull-up).